# AVPlayer in SKVideoNode can't play

Tags: ios, avplayer, skvideonode

I init a `SKVideoNode` with an `AVPlayer` instance, When I call `AVPlayer's` play method, the video don't play. But It can play when I call `SKVideoNode` instance's play method.

The reason I have to use `AVPlayer` not `SKVideoNode` is that I have to monitor the current video's currentTime, play ended status notification. but `SKVideoNode` doesn't have these two property status.

```
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
self.videoNode = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithAVPlayer:self.player];
//some other code are not related to this, so I omit them here

//These two observe can work
[self.player.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.player.currentItem];

//[self.player play]; This method doesn't make video play
[self.videoNode play];//This one does
```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with using both an `SKVideoNode` and an `AVPlayer` together to provide more fine grained control over playback. I am assuming you are using the `SKVideoNode` because `SpriteKit` is being used, if you need anything beyond just play and pause you will also want an `AVPlaye`r.

Just note that even with the `AVPlayer` you are still calling play and pause on the `SKVideoNode`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand. Why do I have to use `SKVideoNode` to play/pause instead of `AVPlayer`? Can you explain that ?

Comment: And I've made a test, If I don't init the `SCNView`, `AVPlayer` can control play/pause.